# Converting a dataframe into a nested JSON after groupby and melt

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
PayeeID     TransactionID     Res_1    Res_2
1001        aa1001234         OK       OK
1001        aa1001235         OK       NOT OK
1002        aa1002567         NOT OK   NOT OK
1002        aa1002568         NOT OK   OK
```

Now I want to have this converted into nested JSON String like follow:

```
[{"PayeeID":1001,{"Trxn_ID":"aa1001234","Final_Status":{"Status_I":"OK","Status_II":"NOT 
OK"},"Trxn_ID":"aa1001338","Final_Status":{"Status_I":"NOT OK","Status_II":"OK"}}},{"PayeeID":1002, 
{"Trxn_ID":"aa1002455","Final_Status":{"Status_I":"NOT OK","Status_II":"NOT 
OK"},"Trxn_ID":"aa1002766","Final_Status":{"Status_I":"OK","Status_II":"OK"}}}]
```

I.e. for each PayeeID there should be nested records.

My approach is as follows:

```
df_m = df.melt(id_vars=['PayeeID','Trxn_ID'],value_vars = ['Status_I','Status_II'],\
         var_name='Status_Type',value_name='Final')
df_g = df_m.groupby(['PayeeID','Trxn_ID']).\
       apply(lambda x : dict(zip(x['Status_Type'],x['Final']))).reset_index().\
       rename(columns={0:'Final_Status'})
j = df_g.to_json(orient='records')
```

But when I see j, I am getting as follows:

```
[{"PayeeID":1001,"Trxn_ID":"aa1001234","Final_Status":{"Status_I":"OK","Status_II":"NOT OK"}}, 
{"PayeeID":1001,"Trxn_ID":"aa1001338","Final_Status":{"Status_I":"NOT OK","Status_II":"OK"}}, 
{"PayeeID":1002,"Trxn_ID":"aa1002455","Final_Status":{"Status_I":"NOT OK","Status_II":"NOT OK"}}, 
{"PayeeID":1002,"Trxn_ID":"aa1002766","Final_Status":{"Status_I":"OK","Status_II":"OK"}}]
```

What I am missing out here.

Comment: The JSON you're looking for is invalid - how can you have an object after the payee ID? The object has no key.

Comment: I am actually trying to get one entry for one `PayeeID`

Comment: You will need to group up the values first. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas doesn't know your desired data format. You need to create that in the dataframe first and then output to JSON. The following gets you one entry per payee.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1001,        "aa1001234",         "OK",       "OK",],
    [1001,        "aa1001235",         "OK",       "NOT OK",],
    [1002,        "aa1002567",         "NOT OK",   "NOT OK",],
    [1002,        "aa1002568",         "NOT OK",   "OK"]], columns=["PayeeID", "TransactionID", "Res_1", "Res_2"])

dfg = df.groupby("PayeeID")["TransactionID",     "Res_1",    "Res_2"].aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x))

dfg.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')


[{
    "PayeeID": 1001,
    "TransactionID": ["aa1001234", "aa1001235"],
    "Res_1": ["OK", "OK"],
    "Res_2": ["OK", "NOT OK"]
}, {
    "PayeeID": 1002,
    "TransactionID": ["aa1002567", "aa1002568"],
    "Res_1": ["NOT OK", "NOT OK"],
    "Res_2": ["NOT OK", "OK"]
}]
```

A potentially better structure could be:

```
df['tx'] = df.apply(lambda x: {x['TransactionID']: {'Res_1':x['Res_1'], 'Res_2':x['Res_2']}}, axis=1)
dfg = df.groupby("PayeeID")["tx"].aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x))
dfg.reset_index().to_json(orient="records")

[{
    "PayeeID": 1001,
    "tx": [{
        "aa1001234": {
            "Res_1": "OK",
            "Res_2": "OK"
        }
    }, {
        "aa1001235": {
            "Res_1": "OK",
            "Res_2": "NOT OK"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "PayeeID": 1002,
    "tx": [{
        "aa1002567": {
            "Res_1": "NOT OK",
            "Res_2": "NOT OK"
        }
    }, {
        "aa1002568": {
            "Res_1": "NOT OK",
            "Res_2": "OK"
        }
    }]
}]
```